# How do I create custom Lifecycle Hooks for Angular Components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, decorator

I want to create custom lifecycle hooks for Angular components.

Two examples are that I want to add hooks based on blur / focus of the browser as well as visibility changes on a browser.  I'd prefer to not add a @HostListener to every component and to use a decorator, but I'm not sure I'll be able to access the parts I need.

One example of an issue I'm running into is trying to open / close an angular material menu and based on the new "lifecycle" hooks.

I'm not sure I'm taking the right approach.  Any other recommended approach that means I don't have to add @HostListener and repeat code everywhere would be appreciated.

Here is a stackblitz of my attempt to use a class decorator.  The component reference is always "undefined" in the lifecycle methods: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7oyay8?file=src/app/menu/menu.component.ts

Here is the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { ExtraHooks } from '../extra-hooks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  template: `
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
@ExtraHooks()
export class AppMenu implements ExtraHooks {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger, { static: false }) matMenuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  constructor() {}

  onFocusIn() {
    console.log('focus in');
    if (this.matMenuTrigger) {
      this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu();
    }
  }

  onFocusOut() {
    console.log('focus out');
    if (this.matMenuTrigger) {
      this.matMenuTrigger.closeMenu();
    }
  }

  onViewHidden() {
    console.log('view hidden');
    if (this.matMenuTrigger) {
      this.matMenuTrigger.closeMenu();
    }
  }

  onViewVisible() {
    console.log('view visible');
    if (this.matMenuTrigger) {
      this.matMenuTrigger.openMenu();
    }
  }
}
```

Class Decorator:

```
export function ExtraHooks() {
  let set = false;
  const watchVisibility = (target: ExtraHooks) => {
    // DOCUMENT VISIBILITY
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function (event) {
      if (document.hidden) {
        target.onViewHidden();
      } else {
        target.onViewVisible();
      }
    });
  };

  const watchFocus = (target: ExtraHooks) => {
    window.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
      target.onFocusIn();
    });

    window.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {
      target.onFocusOut();
    });
  };

  return function (target) {
    // MAKE SURE IT'S NOT SET MORE THAN ONCE
    if (!set) {
      watchFocus(target.prototype);
      watchVisibility(target.prototype);
      set = true;
    }
  };
}

export interface ExtraHooks {
  onFocusIn();
  onFocusOut();
  onViewVisible();
  onViewHidden();
}
```

Comment: For context we're slowly replacing a Winforms app with webviews and we often have 2/3 different webviews mixing with winforms.  We often need to know if the focus has been lost (like a menu closing when clicking on winforms instead of somewhere on the app).

Comment: I also have been looking at Ionic since they have custom component lifecycle hooks, but not successfully at this point.

Comment: For now I just made a component in the library with @Output event emitters with the lifecycle hooks for now. It doesn't really answer this question though, but at least it does not repeat code.

<lifecycle-hook (onFocusIn)="onFocusIn()"...